# Gvim 7.33 (and Vim) have a problem with the command Ctrl+X (next command) in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, gvim

Every time I do the auto-completion Ctrl+X the menu to choose the next step (O, L, etc...) pops up in the command line for just few milliseconds (it should stay until you press the next command). It doesn't happen if I don't open a file and start typing right away in Vim's welcoming page.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: the menu pops up at the position where you have the text. yours is really showing in the command line?? have you set the 'wildmenu' option?

Comment: @akira the pop up line is ok, the previous step is the one who shows up for milliseconts (When you have to pick between L, O, etc..).

Comment: ah, ok. but i can't visualize that since that never happened .. somehow.

Comment: you meant `-- ^X Modus (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)` showing up in the commandline?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Super Tab plugin fixed the problem

Comment: Can you accept this answer so that this question doesn't show up as unresolved?  Thanks.